# iOS certification generation with Codename One

Tags: ios, codenameone, code-signing

I am trying to generate the required certificates to build Apple App, but I get a runtime error while adding a new device via the certificate wizard.

The error reads (RuntimeError) Please login using Spaceship::Portal.login('user','password')

[image: Apple certificate generation under CodenameOne]

Before trying to generate a certificate I first connected successfully to itunes connect with my credentials. The error seems to be related to Fastlane presumably used internally by CodenameOne to generate the certificate.

Moreover I also tried to remove one character in the UDID and I got the same error which is estonishing. However the UDID has been double checked with someone who dictated it to me. So the UDID is a 1-to-1 copy of the one shown in itunes.

Why do I get this error message and what can be done to remove it and be able to add the new device ?

Please note : My setup involves codenameone running under Eclipse Mars under Linux 64.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this.  It should now be fixed.  Please give it another try.

Comment: Thanks for quickky correcting this Steve, I can now add the devices and generate the certificates :-)!